# How to instantiate a new instance of a property in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB.Net I am using a variation of this so when a the SearchModel is used there is an empty list of Tags ready to go.

```
Public Class SearchModel
    Public Property Tags As New List(Of TagDetails)
End Class
```

A simple conversion results in this but "Tags" is null:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public List<TagDetails> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to create the "Tags" property and create a new empty list at the same time?

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public List<TagDetails> Tags = new List<TagDetails>();
}
```

Or should I go through all of this ceremony?

```
public class SearchModel
{
  private List<TagDetails> _TagDetails;
    public List<TagDetails> Tags
    {
        get { return _TagDetails ?? (_TagDetails = new List<TagDetails>()); }
        set { _TagDetails = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conventional way is using a constructor:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public SearchModel()
    {
        Tags = new List<TagDetails>();
    }
    public List<TagDetails> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1. Normally you would make `set` private in this case, so one can't replace List itself, but content is still ok to modify. (Edited answer too).

Comment: Well, only make it a private setter if you want it to be private.  Just because you're instantiating it in the constructor, does not mean you *have* to make it a private setter.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I would agree with Gromer. A private setter is not a must-have with a constructor.

Comment: I tried not to say "must make set private"... Reverted the edit to match your intent.

Answer (score 5):

Instantiate it in the constructor:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public List<TagDetails> Tags { get; set; }

    public SearchModel()
    {
        Tags = new List<TagDetails>();
    }

    public SearchModel(List<TagDetails> tagDetails)
    {
        Tags = tagDetails;
    }
}
```

I did that in C# since you had most of your code in C#.  You can keep the automatic property doing it that way.  You can also add an overloaded constructor that takes in a list to use (delete that if you don't want it).

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward conversion is the following (which is what VB is doing behind the scenes):

```
public class SearchModel
{
    private List<TagDetails> _Tags = new List<TagDetails>();
    public List<TagDetails> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return _Tags;
        }
        set
        {
            _Tags = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also good arguments for not exposing the concrete list class at all. I'd certainly question whether a setter was wise, you could get a right mess in terms of object life times and the garbage collector with that.

```
public class SearchModel
{
    private List<TagDetails> _tags;

    public SearchModel()
    {
        _tags = new List<TagDetails>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TagDetails> Tags {get {return _tags;}}

}
```

Would have been my first attempt and then and add any other list type methods I needed to, Clear, append etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the lazy instantiation of the list:

```
public class SearchModel
{
  private Lazy<List<TagDetails>> tags = new Lazy(() => new List<TagDetails>());

  public List<TagDetails> Tags
  {
    get { return this.tags.Value; }
  }
}
```

However with this you will not be able to set the value.